# Can you specify the lifetime of a moved self parameter?

Tags: rust, lifetime-scoping

I have a newtype struct:

```rust
pub struct Branch<'repo>(Git2Branch<'repo>);
```

And I am trying to wrap a method call:

```rust
impl <'repo> Branch<'_> {
    pub fn into_reference(self) -> Git2Reference<'repo> {
        self.0.into_reference()
    }    
}
```

(`Git2Branch` and `Git2Reference` here are aliases for types of the same name from the git2 crate.)

This fails to compile with

```
error: lifetime may not live long enough
  --> git_wrapper/src/branch.rs:38:9
   |
6  | impl <'repo> Branch<'_> {
   |       ----- lifetime `'repo` defined here
...
37 |     pub fn into_reference(self) -> Git2Reference<'repo> {
   |                           ---- has type `branch::Branch<'1>`
38 |         self.0.into_reference()
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ associated function was supposed to return data with lifetime `'repo` but it is returning data with lifetime `'1`
```

Lifetimes `'1` and `'repo` *should* be the same, but I can't figure out how (or if it's even possible) to specify the lifetime of `self` in this case.

Comment: Is there a reason you are unable to use `impl<'repo> Branch<'repo> {`?

Answer (score 3):

```
impl <'repo> Branch<'_> {
```

Is the same as:

```
impl <'repo, 'anonymous> Branch<'anonymous> {
```

So the lifetimes `'repo` and the anonymous lifetime of the field are unrelated - which causes an issue when you try to return the `Git2Reference<'anonymous>`.

You only need to talk about one lifetime here, so say that:

```
impl <'repo> Branch<'repo> {
```